# problems inserting commas in tables - pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv

I have a table I want to import into an appendix. The last column is a source key, and there are several sources in each cell I want to list as a, b, c; d, f, m; etc. However, the problem is the are commas in a csv file - so to keep them from being read as separate columns, I put brackets around the information for the cell, and also tried putting it around the commas individually. Both these approaches worked - but left weird quotation marks around the text in the pdf. I looked this up in the pgfplotstable manual and on the forums, but mostly it seemed to deal with numbers with commas separating the places or as decimal points, rather than text. (I have an additional table I am importing from a csv that also has commas in the text - i.e. a citation: Last, First. Year. Title. City, State: Publisher. - that I would also like to be able to import with the commas intact without messing up the formatting.) Any ideas on how to include these commas in the text of my final table without confusing LaTex or getting strange formating? Thanks!

```
\begin{filecontents*}{SE_example3.csv}
\textbf{Section 1:},,,
Item 1 has a long description,2000-2010,Short description here,"{a, b, c} "
Item 2 also has a long description,1999-2005,This is a longer description and I need     to keep this description long so I can be sure that the table will wrap,"b{,} c{,} d"
Item 3 is short,1995-2006,This is some text.,c 
\hline \textbf{Section 2:},,,
Item 4,1999-2005,This is some more text.,d
Item 5,1995-2006,Text here,e
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt, english]{article} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.54cm, vmargin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\begin{document} 

\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
% upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
\pgfplotstableset{
    empty header/.style={
      every head row/.style={output empty row},
    }
}
}

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\scriptsize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
empty header,
header=false,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
every first row/.append style={before row={%
\caption{Description of Policies}%
\label{tab:policies}\\\toprule
\textbf{Policy} &\textbf{Years} &\textbf{Description} &\textbf{Sources} \\ \toprule    
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{4}{l}%
{{\bfseries Description of Policies \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule 
%
\textbf{Policy} &\textbf{Years} &\textbf{Description} &\textbf{Sources} \\ \toprule      
\endhead
%
\midrule \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
}},%
%
end table=\end{longtable},
col sep=comma,
string type,
column type=l,
columns/0/.style={column type=p{6cm}},
columns/1/.style={column type=p{1.3cm}},
columns/2/.style={column type=p{6cm}},
columns/3/.style={column type=p{1cm}},
]{SE_example3.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

EDIT: I just realized that Microsoft Word is inserting those " " around the {}; they aren't visible in the editor and I didn't notice until I had imported it as a text file for the purposes of creating the MWE.

Comment: Try to protect the whole entry with braces: `...,{a,b,c},...`

Comment: I had - but I just realized Microsoft Word put quotation marks around those brackets which aren't visible until you look at the text file. I'm not sure why it does that - I don't want to have to manually edit those out of the text file later if I can help it. Is there another solution?

Comment: I guess that MS is using quotes as delimiters for you data file. You can use Excel or Calc (from LibreOffice) to manage your data files. Both can change the delimiter.